# Tuple index out of range error while using np.reshape

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

**dataset** and **train** are both a list of 785 numpy.ndarrays.
each array in dataset and train contains approx 1300 and 950 values respectively

```
x_train1, y_train1 = [],[] #*
for n in range(len(df2)): #*
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(dataset[n]) #*dataset instead of dataset[n]
    x_train, y_train = [], []
    for i in range(60,len(train[n])):              #*train instead of train[n]
        x_train.append(scaled_data[i-60:i,0])
        y_train.append(scaled_data[i,0])
    x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)
    x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1],1)) #here is the error
    x_train1.append(x_train) #*
    y_train1.append(y_train) #*
print(len(x_train1))
```

this is the error
`tuple index out of range`
this code runs fine when dataset and train are array instead of list of array i.e. dataset instead of dataset[n]. And there is no for loop in the * marked section.

*I was refering LSTM code in this, but this site has code for 1 symbol(company)only hence i created lists and for loops.
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/10/predicting-stock-price-machine-learningnd-deep-learning-techniques-python/

Comment: Check the `x_train.shape`.  It may be 1d, possibly because the `x_train` (before `np.array()`) contains arrays that very in size.   Also compare `x_train.dtype` between the working and failed cases.

Comment: Replace this `x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1]` with `*x_train.shape` and check the shape of `x_train` before reshaping it. This will help you to narrow down the search to debug the issue

Answer (score 0):

got it. It happened because there was a particular dataset in dataset[n], whose size was less than 60.